# Criteria API: same query, different resultset types (constructor expressions)

Tags: java, jpa

I have a method, which generates a JPA Criteria:

```
private CriteriaQuery<ResultSetType> createQuery (ReportFilter reportFilter) {
    List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ResultSetType> c = cb.createQuery(ResultSetType.class);
    ...
    c.multiselect(...);
    ...
    return c;
}
```

Now I want to create several queries with different Constructor Expressions (ResultSetType).

What would be the most elegant solution for that? The argument Type is always the same (ReportFilter), but for Different Constructor Expressions (ResultSetType) I want to create a different selections c.multiselect(...).

Any suggestions?

BR, Reen

Comment: Or in other words, how can I use the ResultSetType class as variable. Generics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private <T> CriteriaQuery<T> genericCriteria(ReportFilter reportFilter, Class<T> clazz) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> c = cb.createQuery(clazz);
    ....
    if (clazz.equals(ResultSetType.class)) {
        c.multiselect(...);
    } else {
    }
    ...
    return c;
}
```